# Are there alternatives to UltraWinGrid?

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've been using the Infragistics UltraWinGrid for a while in a C# project, and while it's very spiffy, it is sometimes a bit heavy to run (and editing it in Visual Studio can be hazardous).

I'm looking for a lighter alternative. Looks (always a big plus with Infragistics) are not as important as functionality. Namely, I'm looking for a beefed up DataGridView which:

- has data binding (duh!)
- has lock control over editing
- allows for sub-tables on opening a row
- can have multiple headers to group columns together (say header 1 is composed of "Group A" and "Group B", and header 2 has various columns under each group)
- has sorting by column (and can sort numbers properly, even if it does not have a stock method at first)
- has filtering by column (perhaps the most demanding spec) *à la* UltraWinGrid/Excel (text field with a way to specify if the filter is equal, not equal, greater, lesser, starts with, ends with, etc).
- supports check box, text box or data bound list/combo box cells
- allows cells to be merged (not the control cells of course!)
- can have events bound to each row (say double click)

Comment: this is a windows app ? web app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i've had a good deal of success with the Developer Express grid in the past. In fact i chose it as the grid component of choice over many other 3rd party grid vendors including Infragistics. Not that Infragistics is bad at all. During my research i concluded, as you have, that it was an overly "heavy" component. DexEx also lets you buy the source code affording you the chance to make it even lighter or customizing further.

Link: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [SourceGrid](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/):

Features

What SourceGrid can do:

- It is possible to customize the graphic appearance, the type of editor and the behavior (cursor, tooltiptext, contextmenu ...,) of every cell.
- Supports natively all of the types of data that have a TypeConverter or an UITypeEditor associated.
- Any .NET control can be used like editor with few lines of code.
- You can insert, delete and move rows and columns.
- The height and the width can be customized independently for every columns and rows or can be calculated automatic based to the content of the cells.
- Supports features of RowSpan and ColumnSpan, to unite more cells.
- Supports automatic operations of Copy and Paste.
- Supports natively column sort.
- You can change the width and the height of the columns and rows.
- In every cell is possible to customize the image and the alignment of the text and the image.
- Supports MultiLine and WordWrap text.
- Supports an HTML export.
- With some extension supports data binding features.
- Support virtual cells used to binding any type of data source.

And what cannot do

- SourceGrid doesn't have a designer, all should be done with code.
- No printing support.

Comment: The no printing support makes me cringe, but, oddly enough, not for this project. Must be some kind of base reflex...